# Виджет "Популярные записи" (по просмотрам) для блога WP

Tags: wordpress

Подскажите статью или готовое решение самописного виджета для WordPress, чтобы популярные записи выводил, в зависимости от просмотров, например.
Готовые решения (плагины) слишком громоздкие и не дают возможности тонкой настройки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Простой пример реализации популярных постов без использования плагина.

1) вставить код в файл functions.php вашей темы:

```
function setPostViews($postID) {
  $count_key = 'post_views_count';
  $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
  if($count==»){
  $count = 0;
  delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
  add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, ‘0’);
  }else{
  $count++;
  update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count); } }

function getPostViews($postID){
  $count_key = 'post_views_count';
  $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
  if($count==»){
  delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
  add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, ‘0’);
  return "0"; }
  return $count;}
```

2) Далее код счетчика нужно вставить в файл single.php внутрь цикла loop:

```
<?php setPostViews(get_the_ID()); ?>
```

3) И выводим список популярных статей путем вставки последнего кода в нужное место вашей темы, допустим в сайтбар:

```
<div class="popular">
  <h3 class="widget-title">Популярные статьи</h3>
  <ul>
   <?php
   $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 5, 'meta_key' => 'post_views_count', 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 'order' => 'DESC' ); query_posts($args);
   while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
   <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
   <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
 </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/89025)

Comment: Что за народ. Я привел ответ на свой же вопрос, уверен это интересно не только мне, и нашлись те, кто минусуют.

Comment: Скорее всего минус поставили потому, что в оригинале Ваш ответ, по сути, состоял из ссылки на сторонний ресурс. На данном сайте это не приветствуется. Почему, можно прочитать в [справке](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers) и моём комментарии из очереди проверок. Отредактированная версия - совсем другое дело.